# How to execute a fusion table request using UTF-8 encoded data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I use this fusionRequest function but I can not save accented characters.

I think we have to use UTF-8 encryption, but something is wrong in my code.

Here it is :

```
function fusionRequest(method, sql) {

  var url = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query";

  if (USE_OAUTH) {

    var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_();
  }
  else {
    var fetchArgs = new Object();
    fetchArgs.headers = {
      "Authorization": "GoogleLogin auth=" + getAuthToken_()
    };
  }

  fetchArgs.method = method;

  if (method == 'get') {

    url += '?sql=' + sql;
    fetchArgs.payload = null;
  }
  else {
    fetchArgs.payload = 'sql=' + sql;
  }

  fetchArgs.charset = '"UTF-8"';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);

  var responseText = response.getContentText();

  return response.getContentText();

}
```

thanks in advance for your precious help...

BR

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

For POST, you could try:

```
fetchArgs.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
```

Haven't tested it, but let me know if it works. Otherwise, you could try:

```
fetchArgs.headers["Accept-Charset"] = "UTF-8";
```

Comment: Thank U for your help, but I have try both of your suggestions and it still not working. The syntax "fetchArgs.headers["Content-Type"] = " seems to be uncorrect. I still interested by any other suggestions. Thks.

Comment: Hi all, here is a description of my issues with error messages : I have an issue when I try to save data with accent (UTF-8) in a fusion table (using post method).
For instance ""éric".
I lose my oAuthToken and the error message is "error at the authentification : fusion"
An other issue is when I save data with comma (ie : "12, rue") it make a decalage to my column...
Any idea ?

Comment: just to let you know that we need to transform the url by using this url = encodeURI(url);

Comment: If you still have an issue, please post a new question indicating any new changes you may have made to the code. I apologize that I haven't been that much of help!